# timer using js on php file make input and textarea style return as default

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I'm using a timer on js in php file after a submit to insert data to mysql database the problem is when I press submit the style of textarea and input change and back to the default because of the timer

I tried to submit without the timer the result was good and nothing of the styles change so the problem being with using the timer function

com.php

```
<?php
require('connection.php');

$status = '';
$text = '';
$com = '';
$url = 'index.php';

function timer($url){
    echo' <script>
    setTimeout(function () {
      window.location.href= "'.$url.'";   
       },3000); 
     </script>';

}

if(isset($_POST['addCom'])){
            $com= mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_REQUEST['com']);
            $text= mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_REQUEST['text']);
            $stmt = $db->prepare("insert into testcomments (com,text) values (?,?)");
            $stmt->bind_param('ss',$com,$text);
            $stmt->execute();
            $status = "Done ";
            $com= '';
            timer($url);
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html >
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/registeration1.css">

</head>

<body>

    <form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="input-group">
            <textarea name="com" > </textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="text" > 
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn" name="addCom" id="add" >اضافه</button>
        </div>
        <p style="color:#FF0000;"><?php echo $status; ?></p>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

registeration1.css

```
form {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #B0C4DE;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
.input-group {
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.input-group input  {
    height: 30px;
    width: 93%;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
.btn {
    padding: 15px;
    padding-left:30px;
    padding-right:30px;  
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    background: black;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}



.input-group textarea{
    height: 30px;
    width: 93%;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

I expect no change of the style after using the timer but the actual output is the style of input tag and textarea tag has been change

Comment: From what i see.. you are writing some javascript in the DOM after 3 seconds to redirect to index.php. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont output anything before html opening tag

```
 <?php
    require('connection.php');
    $status = '';
    $text = '';
    $com = '';
    $url = 'index.php';

    function timer($url){
        echo' <script>
        setTimeout(function () {
          window.location.href= "'.$url.'";   
           },3000); 
         </script>';

    }
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html >
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/registeration1.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <?php
                 if(isset($_POST['addCom'])){
                     $com= mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_REQUEST['com']);
                     $text= mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_REQUEST['text']);
                     $stmt = $db->prepare("insert into testcomments (com,text) values (?,?)");
                     $stmt->bind_param('ss',$com,$text);
                     $stmt->execute();
                     $status = "Done ";
                     $com= '';
                     timer($url); //Dont output this before html opening tag
                 }
            ?>
            <form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <textarea name="com" > </textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" name="text" > 
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn" name="addCom" id="add" >اضافه</button>
                </div>
                <p style="color:#FF0000;"><?php echo $status; ?></p>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This answer doesnt make sense since he's not using PHP for creating DOM elements (outputing), only used for the form posted values.

Comment: User is outputing values before html opening tag, this in some cases be cause issues. But yes, your answer is better using header location.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your php part with this:

```
<?php
require('connection.php');

$status = '';
$text = '';
$com = '';
$url = 'index.php';

function timer($url){
    sleep(3);
    header('Location: ' . $url); 
}

if(isset($_POST['addCom'])) {
    $com=  mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_REQUEST['com']);
    $text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_REQUEST['text']);
    $stmt = $db->prepare("insert into testcomments (com,text) values (?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss',$com,$text);
    $stmt->execute();
    $status = "Done ";
    $com= '';
    timer($url);
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer it work but status after the insert doesn't change!